# Vectorizing a Loop in a function

Tags: c++, c++17, vectorization, simd

This might be an extremely novice question as I am just starting to explore parallelization. I did search a lot but was not able to wrap my head around anything. 
I wish to vectorize a loop in a function. The same loop is getting vectorized in main but when calling it as a function. Could anyone please guide me in the correct direction.Code below.
TIA

```
#pragma GCC optimize("03", "unroll-loops", "omit-frame-pointer","inline")
#pragma GCC option("arch=native" ,"tune-native", "n0-zero-upper")
#pragma GCC target("avx")
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

template<typename type>
void runLoop(type a, type b, type c, type result)

{

int N = 200000;
int loop = 100000;
auto time = high_resolution_clock:: now();

for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        result[j] = a[j]+b[j]-c[j]+3*(float)i;
    }
auto end_time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(high_resolution_clock::now() - 
time).count();
    //Sanity check to check whether the loop ran accurately or not
assert( result[2] == ( 2.0f + 0.1335f)+( 1.50f*2.0f + 0.9383f)-(0.33f*2.0f+0.1172f)+3* 
(float)(loop-1));
cout << "Time used: "<< end_time << "s, N * noTests="<<(float(N)*float(loop))<< endl;
}

int main()
{
int N = 200000;
int loop = 100000;
float a[N],b[N],c[N],result[N];
auto time = high_resolution_clock:: now();

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    a[i] =       ((float)i)+ 0.1335f;
    b[i] = 1.50f*((float)i)+ 0.9383f;
    c[i] = 0.33f*((float)i)+ 0.1172f;
}

//This loop runs as intended
for (int i = 0; i < loop; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        result[j] = a[j]+b[j]-c[j]+3*(float)i;
    }

auto end_time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(high_resolution_clock::now() - 
time).count();

//Sanity check to check whether the loop ran accurately or not
assert( result[2] == ( 2.0f + 0.1335f)+( 1.50f*2.0f + 0.9383f)-(0.33f*2.0f+0.1172f)+3* 
(float)(loop-1));

cout << "Time used: "<< end_time << "s, N * noTests="<<(float(N)*float(loop))<< endl;

//This function call is not getting vectorized
//runLoop(a, b, c ,result);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I see it vectorized just fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bxL2So
The problem you might encounter is that the outer loop does not make any sense: you are overwriting the value of `result[j]` every iteration of `i`, so you might as well do `result[j] = a[j] + b[j] - c[j] + 3 * (loop -1);`.

Comment: Thank you @JorgeBellon for replying. The purpose of this code was to just  first-hand experience the time difference between a vectorized and a non-vectorized loop. Also when I am running it in my local machine, the time taken is 1.3 seconds when calling from main and around 5.2 seconds when being called as a function, I was expecting them to have similar run times. I am using gcc -8.4 if that may make any difference.

Comment: It is difficult for me to see what you are really comparing. If you change your code to have a preprocessor guard between the two versions and tell me how to build them, I might be able to see what you are measuring. If you want to understand vectorization there are many good courses available for free, just a quick google and I found https://www.coursera.org/learn/parallelism-ia#syllabus

Comment: Yes I wanted to learn vectorization. Will check out the resource .. thank you

Comment: I suspect `"n0-zero-upper"` is supposed to be `"no"` not `"n0"`.  That's only a good idea for `-march=knl`, and a pretty minor thing for Bulldozer or Zen 1.  (Possibly Zen 2, I don't know how it handles dirty YMM upper halves, but `vzeroupper` is still fairly cheap.)